# Error : Invalid Api key and Bad Request

Tags: webservices, xml

I am hitting a web service and passing a xml request but i am getting a response as `Invalid Api key and Bad request`

My xml request(Payload) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventRequest>
    <createEventRequest>
        <event>
            <eventUserName>N092843</eventUserName>
            <eventComment>POstToLayer7</eventComment>
            <eventMessageExpiry>0</eventMessageExpiry>
        </event>
        <eventPayLoad>
            <paperworkcomplete>
                <quoteId>9023304</quoteId>
                <ReRateRequiredFlag>false</ReRateRequiredFlag>
            </paperworkcomplete>
        </eventPayLoad>
    </createEventRequest>
</eventRequest>
```

I am incuding the following headers

```
Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/xml');
        req.setHeader('content-type','application/xml');
        req.setHeader('aeContentType','application/xml');
        System.debug('accessToken++++++++++++++'+accessToken);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ accessToken);
        req.setHeader('aeMultiPath','3');
        req.setHeader('RequestReceivedDate',todaysDate);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setClientCertificateName(System.Label.WSCertificationName);
         System.debug('Payload+++>: '+payLoad);
        req.setTimeout(120000);//2 min
        req.setBody(payLoad);
        req.setEndPoint(quoteUrl);
```

Any idea guys what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that external service works in external tool. f.e. curl or postman?

Comment: I have not tried that

Comment: Those kind of errors may be caused by 2 reasons -- mistake in your code or mistake in expected external service usage. Both can cause *Bad request* . It is hard to help in scenario 2 because web service details are not exposed in question, and it makes future investigation useless. Please, confirm that your service works as expected and payload is correct

Comment: I will check that

Comment: I am getting the same error with Soap Ui

Comment: So, it mean that there is a problem with your web service, nothing to do with salesforce at this point